# flash message not appearing with devise after_sign_in_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added a devise `after_sign_in_path_for` method and my flash messages are not appearing.  Any idea?

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case current_user.default_role_sym
    when  :super_admin
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Signed in as Super Admin'
      root_url
    when  :company_admin
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Signed in as company admin'
      root_url
    else
      msg = "Signed in as ELSE"
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Signed in as pending client'
      root_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: you use it in application_controller.rb, right? Also you would probably need to check devise.en.yml

Comment: I had it in the session controller, but it started working when I moved it to the application_controller.  thanks!

Comment: Great! I can add it as an answer and you can accept it since that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the method to `application_controller.rb` and you should be good.

Comment: for organizational reasons and to keep the application controller clean, is there a way to get it working in the session controller? logically it seems to make more sense there to me.

Comment: I think it was not treated right by app (before you put it into application_controller) because it is devise's method. So one option (I think) is to overwrite (create a file in app) Devise's sessions controller. But I am not strong yet in such things, truly to say..

Answer (score 2):

After sign in path is called to get the URL to redirect the user to, so after that method is called a 302 redirect is issued from Rails.  The browser will make another request to your rails app for the URL that your returned (root_url in this case).  flash.now is only available during the current request, after the request complete that flash will be empty.  However, if you set flash[:notice] it'll be available on the next request.

Try setting flash[:notice] instead of flash.now[:notice].  See [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) for more information.